# fancybox to show up only the first time when page land on

Tags: php, html

How to install fancybox to show up only the first time when you com to a home page. 
This shall be included:

```
<h1> Please select your language </h1>
<div> class="select-language" </div>
```

The fancybox shall show up only once, regardless which page you land on.

Comment: have you tried anything to make this happen? any research done?

Comment: Hint: store a cookie or session value.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this.

$(document).ready(function{

if (! $.cookie("cookieName")){

// do your stuff

// set cookie now

$.cookie("cookieName", "firstSet", {"expires" : 7})

}

})
```

The above uses the following plugin. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code with cookie,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        $.fancybox({
            'width': '60%',
            'height': '80%',
            'autoScale': true


        });
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 7 });
    });
```

Comment: it is worth mentioning that this requires the cookie plugin.